# Plotting multiple shapefiles in one figure;

Tags: python, shapefile

I am new to python and geopands. I am trying to plot 2 shapefiles on 1 figure using geopadans, here is what I have tried. I got 2 separated figures in stead of 1. Thanks!

```
bdry_line = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(bdry_shapefile)    
myploygons = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(ploy_shapefile) 
bdry_line.plot()
myploygons.plot()
```

Comment: try `ax = bdry_line.plot()` and then `myploygons.plot(axes=ax)` - something similar works with `pandas`

Comment: Thank you, furas, it worked out just like what I wanted.